# Updating Datatable but 1st row is not marked as Modified and therefore won't update SQL table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

**Revised with row state before writing to datatable per Steve's request:**

I have the below code writing to a datatable which is called from hitting a SAVE button on the form.  The changes in the table are eventually sent to a SQL database through a dataadapter, but the first row isn't saving in the database correctly and I have found it's because the first row's state is showing "Unchanged" in the datatable.
I wrapped the statement with console writes to see what is going on.  Can anyone explain to me why its not marking the first row as modified after I write to it?  The rest of the rows do.

Code to write to datatable:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString & " *************** New Entry ***************")

'update datetime in the datatable
Dim rowindex As Integer = 0

For Each row As DataRow In dt_PartData.Rows

    If Not row.RowState = DataRowState.Deleted Then

        Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & " Row state Before: " & row.RowState.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & " Reading Before: " & dt_PartData.rows(rowindex)("LastSaved").ToString)

        dt_PartData.rows(rowindex)("LastSaved") = DateTime.Now.ToString
        Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & " Writing:  " & DateTime.Now.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & " Reading After:  " & dt_PartData.rows(rowindex)("LastSaved").ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & " Row state After: " & row.RowState.ToString)

    End If

    rowindex = rowindex + 1
Next row
```

Below code is a called subroutine called immediately after the above code and just before the SQL statement to update the database:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString & " *************** Saving Entry ***************")

'update datetime in the datatable
Dim rowindex As Integer = 0

For Each row As DataRow In dt_PartData.Rows

    If Not row.RowState = DataRowState.Deleted Then
         Console.WriteLine(rowindex.ToString & ": Row state: " & row.RowState.ToString)
     End If

    rowindex = rowindex + 1
Next row
```

A view of the output window:

```
10/11/2016 9:44:17 AM *************** New Entry *************** In 10min
0 Row state Before: Unchanged
0 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 7:41:27 AM
0 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
0 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
0 Row state After: Unchanged
1 Row state Before: Unchanged
1 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
1 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
1 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
1 Row state After: Modified
2 Row state Before: Unchanged
2 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
2 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
2 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
2 Row state After: Modified
3 Row state Before: Unchanged
3 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
3 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
3 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
3 Row state After: Modified
4 Row state Before: Unchanged
4 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
4 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
4 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
4 Row state After: Modified
5 Row state Before: Unchanged
5 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
5 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
5 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
5 Row state After: Modified
6 Row state Before: Unchanged
6 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
6 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
6 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
6 Row state After: Modified
7 Row state Before: Unchanged
7 Reading Before: 10/11/2016 9:39:55 AM
7 Writing:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
7 Reading After:  10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM
7 Row state After: Modified
10/11/2016 9:44:30 AM *************** Saving Entry ***************
0: Row state: Unchanged
1: Row state: Modified
2: Row state: Modified
3: Row state: Modified
4: Row state: Modified
5: Row state: Modified
6: Row state: Modified
7: Row state: Modified
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time, this forum has been a lot of help to me!

Comment: Could you add the output for the RowState also in the first loop?

Comment: Weird, I am unable to reproduce this behavior with a simple code that travels around a datatable

Comment: I have a datagridview that is sourced to this datatable.  But what I don't get is how anything can happen while that loop is running.  The row clearly changes values, so how can the state not be changed?  Before making changes in the datatable, I was changing the values in the datagridview but that seemed to be cause problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working now.  I have found two solutions that seemed to work for this.

1. I still don't fully understand how this is working for me, but I
   found this post on here that had a similar issue with the first row
   not updating in a datatable and using it as a source to a
   datagridview.
   [Missing Row in Datatable Modified property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962349/missing-row-in-datatable-modified-property/3969043#3969043)

So I added this line of code before making changes to the datatable:

```
BindingContext(dt_PartData).EndCurrentEdit()
```

Or this:

2.
 Setting the datagridview.DataSource to nothing and then make changes to the datatable, then put the .DataSource back to the datatable.

```
DataGridViewPartData.DataSource = Nothing

     (make changes to the datatable here)

DataGridViewPartData.DataSource = dt_PartData
```

Comment: Big thanks! I had the same issue, the first modified gridview row (by primary key) was never updated in database. I did a similar fix as EndEdit on dataTable had no effect for me, instead I sent BindingSource.EndEdit.
      MyBindingSource.EndEdit()